# PHP update associative array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, associative-array

I wish to update just the ["distanceTimeFromNextPoint"] element in an associative array I have created in PHP.

I am trying to update the following array structure:

```
Array 
( 
  [0] => Array 
  ( 
    [Total time] => 0:00 
    [0] => Array 
    ( 
      [place] => Spanish steps  
      [distanceTimeFromNextPoint] =>  
    ) 
    [1] => Array 
    ( 
      [place] => Piazza Venezia 
      [distanceTimeFromNextPoint] =>  
    ) 
  ) 
  [1] => Array 
  ( 
    [Total time] => x0:00 
    [0] => Array  
    ( 
      [place] => Piazza Venezia 
      [distanceTimeFromNextPoint] => 
    ) 
    [1] => Array 
    ( 
      [place] => Spanish steps 
      [distanceTimeFromNextPoint] => 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

**But when I am running this loop the ["Total time"] element also gets updated!** 
Any thoughts about what's wrong with my loop and how can I change it?

This is my code (the array above is defined as $new_array):

```
foreach($new_array as $i=>$element)
{
    foreach($element as $j=>$sub_element)
    {         
         $new_array[$i][$j]['distanceTimeFromNextPoint']="x";
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got the structure right, just add a condition wherein you're excluding that key and checking if that element has that desired sub key, then make the revision:

```
foreach($new_array as $i => $element) {
    foreach($element as $j => $sub_element) {
        if($j !== 'Total time' && array_key_exists('distanceTimeFromNextPoint', $sub_element)) {
            $new_array[$i][$j]['distanceTimeFromNextPoint'] = 'x';
        }
    }
}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/9FNRYq)

Answer (score 0):

You should test if the element 'distanceTimeFromNextPoint' already exist.

```
if (is_array($new_array[$i][$j]) && array_key_exists('distanceTimeFromNextPoint', $new_array[$i][$j])) 
{
    // you can update it
}
```

Comment: I am getting the error of: Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in

Comment: You should add if the element is an array using is_array function i will edit my response